# HTML Object resize in internet explorer 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, html-object

I have a flash that I'm displaying on the popup window. When I resize the window; The width of the flash increases while the height remains constant.

```
var objectNode = document.createElement("object");
objectNode.appendChild(param); 
objectNode.id = viewerId;
objectNode.width = "100%";
objectNode.height = "100%";
objectNode.classid = "clsid:" + SOME_ID;
containerObject.appendChild(objectNode);
```

containerObject is a HTMLDivElement. This ofcourse works in all browsers except internet explorer 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who might one day face this issue:

There were multiple issues in this.

1. Setting width and height attributes as shown in the question doesn't work.
2. In internet explorer height:100% will be ignored if it's parents' heights are not 100%

Changing containerObject's, body's and html's height in this case to 100% fixed the issue.

```
var htm = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.height="100%";
var bod = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.height="100%";
var objectN = document.createElement("object");
containerObject.setAttribute("style", "height:100%");
objectN.appendChild(param);
objectN.setAttribute("id", "viewer");
objectN.setAttribute("style", "width:100%;height:100%;");
objectN.setAttribute("classid", "clsid:" + PLUGIN_CLSID)
containerObject.appendChild(objectN);
```